# How to count of open files by a user in linux

Tags: linux, ulimit

Is their any specific command to count of open files (nofile) by a user in linux?

Comment: Open a terminal, type the command `man lsof`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -u root | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | wc -l
```

Comment: You can drop the grep by using `lsof -u root`, and since you're only outputting a count (and not making it unique) the awk and sort are also unneeded.